# How to show git status and conda environment in command prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, git, anaconda, bashrc

I am using the [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) script to show the git status at the bash command prompt. Using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` method to also have colors:

*.bashrc* :

```
source ~/.bash.d/git-prompt.sh # Show git branch name at command prompt
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=true 

# use existing PS1 settings
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(sed -r 's|^(.+)(\\\$\s*)$|__git_ps1 "\1" "\2"|' <<< $PS1)
```

This works so far in regard of showing the git status, but it does not show the conda environment anymore.

When I comment out the line with `PROMPT_COMMAND=...`, the conda env is displayed, e.g.

```
(base) [user@linux ~]$
```

Apparently the problem is that git-prompt.sh uses PROMPT_COMMAND and conda  uses PS1.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe showing the conda env with PROMPT_COMMAND?

Answer (score 3):

You can just configure your PS1 to show the git branch by adding a function right above your PS1 declaration:

```
git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

Then, you simply place `\$(git_branch)` wherever you'd like in your PS1, and colorize it as usual.

If you need more details, [this blog](https://blog.keyboardplaying.org/2015/11/21/howto-show-git-branch-linux-prompt/) shows you how.

Comment: It works and does the show the git branch. I think it should be `$(git_branch)` though (without the \\). But it doesn't provide all the features you get with git-prompt.sh and PROMPT_COMMAND

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the following line at the end of your bashrc.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "${CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER}${YOUR_PROMPT}" ...'
```

as an example mine looks like this

```
ORIG_PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w"
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "${CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER}${ORIG_PS1}" "\n\\[\033[00m\]> "'
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise using the bellow instead of parsing `git branch`, as it could take much longer when there are many branches

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git symbolic-ref HEAD --short 2> /dev/null
}
```